# How to return false to parent event from its child in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Here is my js code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#buyer').on('submit', function (event) {
        var userCaptcha = $('#jCaptcha').val();
        $.post('Jcaptcha', {
            jcaptcha: userCaptcha
        }, function (responseText) {
            if (responseText !== "") {
                $('#ajaxcall').html(responseText);
                //return from here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I want to return `false` to my submit event so that form should not get submit.

Comment: Then do so! What is your question?

Comment: @connexo he can't return from there as it will return from the `$.ajax` handler, not the `submit` handler.

Comment: i doubt you can asynchronously run `event.preventDefault()` inside the ajax callback, can you?

Comment: First add Ajax **async** to false and then use event.preventDefault() in ajax callback end....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the form from submitting in the first place, not inside the ajax callback, using `event.preventDefault();`. Your actual submit must be handled via ajax - I assume this is what happens in your `$.post`.

```
$(function () {
  $('#buyer').on('submit', function (event){
    event.preventDefault(); // dont actually submit natively
    var userCaptcha = $('#jCaptcha').val();
    $.post('Jcaptcha', { jcaptcha : userCaptcha }, function (responseText) {
        if (responseText !== "") {
            $('#ajaxcall').html(responseText);            
        }
    });
  });
});
```